# Adding COG GeoTIFF image to GeoServer: Lots of reader and projection issues

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-rest-api, cloud-optimized-geotiff

I'm trying to follow this tutorial: https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/community/cog/mosaic.html?highlight=install

With this GeoTiff: https://noaa-nbm-pds.s3.amazonaws.com/blendv4.1/hawaii/2023/04/07/1200/probqpf12gt200/blendv4.1_hawaii_probqpf12gt200_2023-04-07T12%3A00_2023-04-09T06%3A00.tif

And I have hit roadblock after roadblock.

I am successfully creating the empty ImageMosaic using these settings.

```ini
// indexer.properties
Cog=true
PropertyCollectors=TimestampFileNameExtractorSPI[timeregex](time)
TimeAttribute=time
Schema=*the_geom:Polygon,location:String,time:java.util.Date
CanBeEmpty=true
Name=name
```

```
// timeregex.properties
regex=[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}%3A[0-9]{2}.tif,format=yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH'%3A'mm
```

But as soon as I move to step #2 where I try and prototype the coveragestore I keep getting all sorts of errors.

First was an error related to the funky projection of the tiff. I fixed this by force reprojecting into EPSG:4326 using QGIS and switching to manually loading in the generated test geotiff (for now).

Now I'm having issues where it's failing to create the reader (whatever that means)

```
requested to prototype granules with response: 500,  Failed to create reader from file:data/noaa_nbm_pds/blendv4.1_hawaii_probqpf12gt200 and hints Hints:
  EXECUTOR_SERVICE = java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@1da7bb7b[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
  REPOSITORY       = org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogRepository@42818925                                                                                   
System defaults:
  LENIENT_DATUM_SHIFT              = true                                                   
  COMPARISON_TOLERANCE             = 1.0E-8                                                 
  STYLE_FACTORY                    = StyleFactoryImpl                                       
  LOCAL_DATE_TIME_HANDLING         = true                                                   
  GRID_COVERAGE_FACTORY            = GridCoverageFactory                                    
    TILE_ENCODING                  = null                                                   
  FEATURE_FACTORY                  = org.geotools.feature.LenientFeatureFactoryImpl@19f95540
  FILTER_FACTORY                   = FilterFactoryImpl                                      
  FORCE_LONGITUDE_FIRST_AXIS_ORDER = true                                                   
  FORCE_AXIS_ORDER_HONORING        = http
```

I've confirmed that the file is being uploaded to the data directory for the layer.  I even straight dropped it into my data directory and loaded it with this request.

```
const response = await fetch(`${baseUrl}/geoserver/rest/workspaces/${workspace}/coveragestores/${key}/external.imagemosaic`, {
   method: 'POST',
   headers: {
       ...headers, // Auth
       'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
   },
   body: '/data/hawaii.tif'
});
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure `'Content-Type': 'text/plain'` is correct, I think it should be `image/tiff`